# Getting a high s value rejection although s < N/2

Tags: transactions, signature, raw

Using the mempool app on my full node from mynode, when transmitting a raw tx with more than one output I get:
*non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (Non-canonical signature: S value is unnecessarily high).*
I checked and
**s - N/2 = -2.3646232789023417e+76**,
so this doesn't seem to be true. Using a public block explorer like blockcypher no error is returned, however the tx is stuck and will not confirm.

rax tx is

```
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
```

what could be the reason the tx gets rejected?

Answer (score 1):

The S value in your scriptSig is

```
00a270c846b69cdf68b0c211b67515f850663a6c448c52e6b940863b450a2bf790
```

Interpreted as a hexadecimal number, that is around 7.347395059744133e+76, or (N/2) + 1.5577905978783233e+76.

Comment: Thanks, I look into it.